# Application segmentation fault, only when compiling on Windows with MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to compile [one of my games](http://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVOpenHexagon) on Windows, but unfortunately, no matter what, I'm getting this segmentation fault every time I run the program.

Compilation is successful, and without any warning.

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>
> __chkstk_ms () at ../../../../../src/gcc-4.8.1/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S:172
>
> 172     ../../../../../src/gcc-4.8.1/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S: No such file or directory.

I've tried:

- Compiling on a Windows x86 machine
- Compiling on a Windows x64 machine
- nuwen.net's MinGW distro
- TDM MinGW 4.8.1 SJLJ
- MinGW builds x86 SJLJ
- MinGW builds x64 SJLJ
- MinGW builds x86 DW2

I've built all dependencies from source multiple times, tried linking both statically and dynamically.

Debugging doesn't help either - GDB gives me that error message just upon entering `main()`. I've used `-g3` and `-O0` flags.

How can I figure out what's happening?

Comment: Choose one type of build and stick with it when diagnosing the problem.  Doing multiple builds to attempt to fix an error that you aren't sure about is not the way to go about this.  All that will do is confuse the issue.  Having said that, I am surprised that gdb doesn't have a way to debug code before main() is executed.  How would you debug a constructor of a globally declared object if you can't debug before main() is executed?

Comment: `-fstack-usage` might help you figure what's using a lot of stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, the default stack size is smaller than Linux. __chkstk_ms appears to be a function that crashes if you overflow your stack.

You may try to figure out where in your code you are creating huge stack variables or doing very deep recursion, and fix that.

Alternately, you may be able to add a compile flag to increase the stack size. See http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/13960.

Comment: Is there any way I can find out where the problem is with GDB?

Comment: Yes, you could download the Cygwin libgcc source. Alternately you can try "x/4096a $esp" to dump the stack addresses, which may give you a hint as to what the function call stack is.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - Do you really need tools (except for a code editor) to see if you are declaring local arrays that take up a huge amount of memory?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I'm quite sure I'm not declaring any local array taking up a huge amount of memory. My codebase is also quite large.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - Do you have global variables?  More to the point, have you declared global objects?  If so, those objects need to be constructed before main() is executed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: does this apply also to `static` variables inside global functions? Example: `const std::string& getStaticStr() { static std::string s; return s; }`

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - When that line with the static declaration gets executed, the string is created.  One note is that if more than one thread hits that function, then you have a potential race condition for pre-C++11 compilers (C++11 now guarantees that static variables are created once, and no race condition will occur).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I've read more about static variables, and as far as I understand they shouldn't be allocated on the stack - therefore, that can't be the cause of the problem, I guess

Comment: A friend of mine came to me with the exact same issue. I said "guy, you have a ~8 MB stack which is just too big." We swapped out the stack data into the heap and it worked immediately. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase stack size. Don't ask me how, I don't know.

The failing call (__chkstk_ms) looks like internal routine which checks if there is enough stack space for the function about to be executed.

Comment: and it's also used inside `alloca()` IIRC, so maybe there's an alloca call requesting too much stack causing, yup, stackoverflow