# GNAT-GPS 2015 and cygwin.S issue

Tags: c++, ada, gnat, gnat-gps

I am running an Ada project in GPS-GNAT 2015 that has a C++ User Interface and when debugging I reach the point where I attempt to send data from Ada to the C++ window however I am receiving an error:

> __chkstk_ms () ../../../src/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S 168 no such file or directory found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: looks like the debugger failing to find the cygwin.S file ...?

Comment: Which implies it's trying to get helpful info after a crash. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392755/application-segmentation-fault-only-when-compiling-on-windows-with-mingw (somewhat related) Sorry I can't be more specific but searching "set stack size cygwin" gets quite a bit of discussion.

Comment: https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2003-03/msg01394.html seems closest - `gcc -Wl,--stack,8388608 -o your.exe your.source.adb` Not sure where you add build arguments in gps, but I expect someone here does.

Comment: Go to Project/Properties, go to the vertical tab Switches, go to the horizontal tab Ada Linker, type `-Wl,--stack,8388608` in the field at the bottom (click on the Debug checkbox to see where I mean).

Comment: Thanks guys that helped alot. @BrianDrummond

Comment: OK. Might be worth adding -fstack-protection to the build flags then.